# Plotting County level data using usmap

Tags: r, usmap

thanks for having a look at my question.

I am trying to plot the values on a US map at county level.

This is the data I am using

```
Fips County   Value
01001 Autauga 381.2
1003 Baldwin  366.1
1005 Barbour  547.6
1007 Bibb     501.0
1009 Blount   435.0
01011 Bullock 445.4
01013 Butler 412.9
```

This is the code I am using

```
plot_usmap(
  regions = "counties",
  data = Heart,
  values = "Value",
  labels = FALSE,
  label_color = "black",
)
```

Error in map_with_data(data, values = values, include = include, exclude = exclude) :
`data` must be a data.frame containing either a `state` or `fips` column

I am not sure why I am receiving an error because there is a fips column

Thanks for you help!

Comment: There is a `Fips` column but no `fips` column. Try with renaming your `Fips` column to lower case.